# Iterate over multiple checkboxes and get titles of selected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, checkbox

I have an app with a window containing a box that contains maybe 100 checkboxes.

When I press a button I'd like to build a string of the titles of the selected checkboxes.

I know I need to iterate over all the checkboxes and get the titles but I can't figure out how to do that.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  I know how to do it with bindings and tags but with 100 checkboxes that's just crazy!

Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't use a tableview or a collectionView with multiple selection and you get the selected indexs?

Comment: What do you mean by selected checkboxes?  How do you select checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use a stack view or a collection view. If you want to use simple checkboxes you have to keep pointers either in an array to iterate over or put them in a custom view as container where you iterate over its subviews.

This example will point you in a direction:

```
NSMutableArray *activeButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSView* subview in [self.container subviews])
    if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[NSButton class]] && [(NSButton*)subview state] == 1)
        [activeButtons addObject:[(NSButton*)subview title]];

NSString* text = [activeButtons componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"Active: %@",text);
```

The isMemberOfClass method will ensure to only get buttons and not texts. you may additionaly check for the kind of button to ensure to only get checkboxes if you also have other buttons in the container. There are faster ways like enumeration but this is a better starting point imho.

Note: written on mobile... untested so excuse a possible typo (though double checked)

Comment: Thanks, I'm hung up on how to access the box view...  I'm not sure what to put here: `[self.container subviews]`  I get "property container not found on object type AppDelegate"  I'm guessing this is pretty basic... sigh.

Comment: ouch. this is very basic. you should start with some basic tutorials. You should not use the AppDelegate for views. 1. Learn what a viewController is - 2. Learn how to connect IBOutlets with a vuewController 3. Whole code has to be in an IBAction in a viewController. Even if this sounds completely spanish to you its one of the most basic things. And: if an answer is correct you should accept it (hook) or if it brings you forward you should upvote it. good luck

Comment: Thanks for the code, direction and most of all not being snarky- your clear code, explanation and pointers were very helpful and with a bit of effort and tweaking I've achieved my goal.